# Loading Image orientation wrong

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

Hi I used the picasso library for load the image from server url. But some of images loading in wrong orientation. ExifInterface is class to find out the image orientation but here image is not in resource folder. I have only image url but i want to show the image in correct orientation. How I can achieve to show the image on imageview with correct view.

```
Picasso.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .resize(200, 200)
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_pic)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_pic)
            .into(holder.image);
```

Comment: In which size your images comes?

Comment: size is not matter. some images shows landscape way on imageview. I want to show all images in portrait mode for correct view

Comment: So it depends on the width and height of Image

Comment: so how to show those images in portrait view?

Comment: I think you need to modify height and width while loads the images and check the width and height.

Comment: You should check this link from where you can get image dimension http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522847/getting-image-width-and-height-with-picasso-library. Also you can use Transformer property for picasso to get the dimensions.