# How to show progressbar using Volley/ Glide/Picasso or other , while image downloading from server

Tags: android, android-volley, picasso, android-glide, image-loading

I want to show progress bar(showing percentage) using  Volley/ Glide/Picasso or other network call libraries. There are a lot of solutions but not by the  Volley/ Glide/Picasso, how can I get file image size before downloading and with time remaining size so that I can show with the progress bar.

Use Picasso.

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(server_url).into(image_download);
```

using Glide

```
 GlideApp
.with(myFragment)
.load(url)
.centerCrop()
.placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
.into(myImageView);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using glide

```
progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(imageUrl)
                .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(imageview);
```

with **`Picasso`**

```
Picasso.with(context)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .into(imageview, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            //do something when picture is loaded successfully
                             progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            //do something when there is picture loading error
                        }
                    });
```

with **`AsyncTask`**

```
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage, ProgressBar progressBar) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error", e.getStackTrace().toString());

        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

use like this

```
 new DownloadImage(imamgeview,progressBar).execute(url);
```

Comment: I need to show the file size while downloading like "downloading 75/100 %

Comment: @M.ArslanKhan than you have. to use asynctask to load image from url

Comment: but my question is again same how I can get the file size by Picasso while downloading so that I can show and update while downloading

Comment: thank you so much , how can i get the exact size of the image in AsyncTask for example to show 100kb/1700kb downloading

Comment: @M.ArslanKhan use this to find size of image https://stackoverflow.com/a/37365690/7666442

Answer (score 0):

You can create layout with the target ImageView and progress bar. After load start/end you can hide or show your progress. 
Other examples [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826459/animated-loading-image-in-picasso)

Comment: I need to show the file size while downling(like showing percentage)